# Multiple Choice Test - Incorrect Scores based on answer combinations

Tags: javascript

function getScore(){

```
var q1 = document.test.q1.value;
var q2 = document.test.q2.value;
var q3 = document.test.q3.value;
var q4 = document.test.q4.value;
var score = 0;


if (q1 == "1-25") {
    score += 0;
}
else if (q1 == "26-40"){
    score += 5;
}
else if (q1 == "41-60"){
    score += 8;
}
else
    score += 10;


if (q2 == "0-25"){
    score += 0;
}
else if (q2 == "26-30"){
    score += 0;
}
else if (q2 == "31-35"){
    score += 9;
}
else 
    score += 10;    



if (q3 == "No."){
    score += 0;
}
else if (q3 == "Grandparent"){
    score += 7;
}
else if (q3 == "Sibling"){
    score += 15;
}
else 
    score += 15;


if (q4 == "Low Sugar") {
    score += 0;
}
else if (q4 == "Normal Sugar"){
    score += 0;
}
else if (q4 == "Quite High Sugar?"){
    score +=  7;
}
else 
    score += 10;
```

it seems when i try different combinations of answers , it doesn't produce the correct score in most of the combinations possible

**How old are you?**

1-25 - 0
26-40 - 5
41-60  - 8
60+ 10 - 10

**What is your BMI?**

0-25 0
26-30 0
31-35 9
35+ 10

**Does anybody in
your family have
diabetes?**

No. 0
Grandparent 7
Sibling 15
Parent 15

**How would you
describe your diet?**

Low sugar 0
Normal sugar 0
Quite high sugar? 7
High sugar 10

Comment: Let me ask you a question? What exactly is your question?

Comment: You need to show all your code, not just the if/else calculations

Comment: Ok slow down. First of all, use `switch` statements (I can help you with that). Second, it's unclear what you're asking. Three you need to post your HTML code, and it would be very much appreciated if you create a [fiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.com), you'll get much better answers. Four, what do you mean by incorrect? Show any relevant debugging information.

Comment: Use a switch statement okay, I've not had much practice using this before .  By incorrect i mean if i choose the first answer for all questions and the score stores a value of 15

Comment: update: switch statement has correct the errors thanks so much